# How are globular clusters formed?

Tags: globular-clusters

It is said globular clusters are usually very old and that they orbit around galaxies. But, I never read the reason why globular clusters are old, have that shape, and orbit around galaxies. What is their history?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globular_cluster#Formation